# SwiftUI's Settings window for macOS does not show up on a Catalyst app

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have a simple app with an iOS target that is configured for iPhone, iPad, and Mac, making it a [Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/) app. On Xcode 12.0 Beta 1, I tried adding a [Settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings) scene to my app. The documentation page says it is compatible with both macOS 11.0+ and
Mac Catalyst 14.0+. The entirety of my app is this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestSettingsApp: App {
  @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Text("Hello, world!").padding()
    }
    
    #if os(macOS)
    Settings {
      Text("Settings here.")
    }
    #endif
  }
}
```

Based on the [WWDC 2020 What's new in SwiftUI video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10041/) (4:50), I would expect this to automatically add a "Preferences..." menu option, which would show "Settings here." However, this option never shows up. I also tried replacing `#if os(macOS)` with `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`, which had no effect.

Comment: Reproduced in Xcode 12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Apple's documentation was either incorrect early on in the beta period, or they decided not to implement Settings for Mac Catalyst. The [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings) I referred to earlier has since been updated to remove "Mac Catalyst 14.0+".